# Sci-fi book about a man on the run due to uncovering some conspiracy to destroy the galaxy

Tags: story-identification, novel, space

I read this book in the 1990s, can't remember the title of it.

Pretty much a man who is accused of some crime and is on the run due to uncovering some conspiracy to destroy the galaxy.

The only notable thing about the novel was that there was a woman who accompanied him and she had dye-able tattoos which change color.

All I remember that it was supposed to be part of an omnibus but due to work I didn't have a chance to go back to it.

Comment: Interesting link while searching: [colour-changing tattoos may be coming!](https://www.fastcompany.com/90127275/these-tattoos-change-colors-based-on-the-health-of-your-body).